# How to solve "Conversion Error setting value '2013-10-26' for 'null Converter'" in h:inputText with Date value?

Tags: date, jsf, converters

when I press the insert button, I get the error indicated on the title

> Conversion Error setting value '2013-10-26' for 'null Converter'

```
<h:form id="formulario">
   <h:outputLabel for="date">Plazo</h:outputLabel>
   <h:inputText id="date" required="true" requiredMessage="Campo Obligatorio" value="#{aaaNewDetalles.criterioAaa.plazo}"/>
   <h:message for="date" style="color: red;"/>
   <h:commandButton actionListener="#{aaaNewDetalles.add()}" value="Ingresar"/>
</h:form>
```

the form is managed by this class:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "aaaNewDetalles")
@ViewScoped
public class aaaNewDetallesBean {
     private CriterioAaaController controller;
     private CriterioAaa criterioAaa;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
          controller= new CriterioAaaController();
          criterioAaa= new CriterioAaa();
    }

    public void add(){
        controller.save(criterioAaa);
    }

    public CriterioAaa getCriterioAaa() {
        return criterioAaa;
    }

    public void setCriterioAaa(CriterioAaa criterioAaa) {
        this.criterioAaa = criterioAaa;
    }
}
```

The object CriterioAaa:

```
import java.sql.Date;

@Table(name = "criterio_aaa", schema = "", catalog = "ciclos_calidad")
@Entity
public class CriterioAaa extends Entidad implements Serializable {

    private Date plazo;

    public Date getPlazo() {
        return plazo;
    }

    public void setPlazo(Date plazo) {
        this.plazo = plazo;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two problems in your current approach:

1. You should use `java.util.Date` instead `java.sql.Date`. JSF and other frameworks work with this type. Also, `java.sql.Date` extends `java.util.Date` but its purpose is basically for JDBC usage. More info about this: [Date vs TimeStamp vs calendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17916666/1065197)
2. `<h:inputText>` expects a `String` as value, and when sending the data to the managed bean, it also expects the class field is from `String` type as well. In cases like this, you need to use a converter to tell JSF that this `String` in fact represents a `Date`. For this, you may use `<f:convertDateTime>` tag component.

   ```
   <h:inputText id="date" required="true" requiredMessage="Campo Obligatorio"
       value="#{aaaNewDetalles.criterioAaa.plazo}">
       <f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" />
   </h:inputText>
   ```

As a recommendation, you may use a calendar component from third party libraries like PrimeFaces or RichFaces whose provide [`<p:calendar>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/calendarBasic.jsf) and [`<rich:calendar>`](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=calendar&skin=blueSky) component respectively.

Comment: RichFaces has reached [end-of-life](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/RichFacesEnd-Of-LifeQuestionsAnswers), so using a different framework would be wise.

Answer (score 0):

You should import the appropriate `Date` package :

```
import java.util.Date;
```

Comment: That's only part of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Managed Bean You should use java.util.Date. and specify the converter.
e.g.

```
<h:inputText id="date" required="true" requiredMessage="Hire Date"
value="#{empBean.empDetail.hireDate}">
<f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" />
</h:inputText>
```

you can specify the pattern for DateTimeConverter also you can use dateStyle,timeStyle, type.

Comment: Why in earth are you repeating an already given answer? If you agree an answer, just upvote it instead of repeating it. Stack Overflow isn't an old fashioned discussion forum wherein everyone repeats each other into an undigestable mess upon (dis)agreement. Stack Overflow is a clean Question & Answer site wherein everyone can vote each other upon (dis)agreement.