# How to convert a date format to mysql date format?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, date, date-format

I have bunch of dates in a format like `Jan. 14,2014`,`Apr. 20,2014`,`Aug. 14,2014` etc,. which are extracted from a set of PDF documents.

***My Problem*** 
I added the above dates to a mysql column with Column Datatype as Date using java (by PreparedStatement).

```
....
st.SetDate(3,"Jan. 14,2014");
....
```

I added the datas using ExecuteQuery.

But when program executes an error message returned by MySql stating that the date formats are incompatible with MySql column type) Date..

***My Question*** 
How to convert this above mentioned date formats into mysql compatible Date formats ?

Comment: That code wouldn't even compile, as far as I can see - `PreparedStatement.setDate` takes a `Date`, not a `String`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By your current posted code:

```
st.SetDate(3,"Jan. 14,2014");
```

This does not even compile. You could try getting a new `Date` object from a `String` (since this is what you're trying to accomplish), so use a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM. dd,yyyy");
Date date = sdf.parse("Jan. 14,2014");
st.setDate(3, new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()));
//rest of your code...
```

Similar to this, you can parse time or date and time into a `java.util.Date` using `SimpleDateFormat` and then convert it to the respective class `java.sql.Time` and `java.sql.Timestamp` using `date.getTime()`.

Also note that you can p̶a̶s̶s̶  retrieve a `java.util.Date` object reference to `PreparedStatement#getDate` (and `getTime` and `getTimestamp`) since `java.sql.Date`, `java.sql.Time` and `java.sql.Timestamp` extend from `java.util.Date`. For more info, please refer here: [Date vs TimeStamp vs calendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17916666/1065197)

Comment: I don't think that last statement make sense. PreparedStatement#setDate expects a java.sql.Date, making java.util.Date incompatible

Comment: @MadProgrammer you're right, I got confused with `PreparedStatement#getDate` =\. Editing my answer (and ashamed).

Comment: I had to go look it up myself to be sure :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer answer edited (and hopefully with no more misleadings).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the column type supports a `Date` value, you could use a `SimpleDateFormat` to parse the `String` values to a `java.util.Date` and create a `java.sql.Date` which can be applied to the `setDate` method...

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM. dd,yyyy");
Date date = sdf.parse("Jan. 14,2014");
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
```

Check it [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more details

Comment: Seems like we got the same idea.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use the String datatype instead of date in your table.

Comment: That's a very bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to get the string representation of the date to a Date Object. 
This date object can then be used to feed the set date method of the prepared statement.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(....)
java.util.Date date = sdf.parse(....);

preparedStmt.setDate(...., date);
```

Answer (score 0):

first convert the java.util.Date  to java.sql.Date then try to set the Java.sql.Date

you can use this logic to convert

If your date is String then first convert it into Java.util.Date type either by using the SimpleDateFormat or DateFormat

If u want to use a DateFormat you can use it also:
But this changes the expected date format depending on the locale settings of the machine it's running on.

If you have a specific date format, you can use SimpleDateFormat:

```
 Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM. dd,yyyy").parse("Jan. 14,2014");

     java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(d.getTime());
```

Comment: `java.sql.Date` extends from `java.util.Date`, so just pass a `java.util.Date` object reference, there's no need to perform all this logic.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I could be wrong abut to, but PreparedStatement#setDate expected a java.sql.Date, making java.util.Date incompatible, but you can pass java.sql.Date to methods that expect java.util.Date

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes java.sql.Date extends java.util.Date my friend

Comment: @girishlalwani2010 But that doesn't mean that `java.util.Date` can be treated can be treated as a `java.sql.Date` ... or are you agreeing with me (it's like 35 degrees and my brain has melted ;))

Comment: @Ragesh D Antony have you got that

Comment: Yeah, that was for `getDate`, not `setDate`, my vision is blurry at this time of the night =\

Answer (score 0):

I don't really think this all java stuff is necessary. You can simply use this very easy sql process to insert date: `NOW()` in mysql query like `INSERT INTO table_name(c1,c2,datecolumn) VALUES('value1','value2',NOW());` It is much simplier I think :D