# How to get TIME out of DATETIME MySQL using java.sql.Date

Tags: java, mysql, sql, datetime

I have a DATA/TIME field in my MySQL database and I'm trying to convert it to date and time in Java. The date works fine, but in time is set to null. I have tried util.Date as well but I get the same result. How can I convert a DATE/TIME to java.sql.Date without losing the time?

This is my code

```
 try{
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT orders.id, orders.date         FROM user, orders " +
                "WHERE user.username='" + user.getUsername() + "' AND user.id = orders.user");
        while(resultSet.next()){
            Order order = new Order();
            order.setId(resultSet.getInt(1));
            order.setUser(user);
            order.setDate(resultSet.getDate(2));
            System.out.print(order.getDate());
            System.out.print( " -> " + order);
            orders.add(order);
    }catch(SQLException ex){
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17916666/1065197

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
java.sql.Date date = new Date(resultSet.getTimestamp(2).getTime());
```

Comment: And then convert Timestamp to Date?

Answer (score 0):

You are not asking this, but you could save the date as a long in mysql and just treat it as a number.

To get the date back just do a new java.util.Date(mysqllong).

Comment: Yes i thought of that, but i dont decide the fields of my mysql database.