# How do I pass a Date as SQL parameter in Java without losing the time part?

Tags: java, sql

For example, I have this String: 06/10/2013 18:29:09. I want to convert this string and put it in a SQL database (as Date).

How can I convert this to an sql date, so that it could be inserted into a database? I want the hours minutes and seconds to remain as well.

I tried the following:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Date javaDate = sdf.parse("06/10/2013 18:29:09");
java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(javaDate.getTime());
```

Comment: You probably are looking for [java.sql.Timestamp](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) since java.sql.Date or java.sql.Time doesn't support format you described.

Comment: I'm not sure i get totally what you mean but is it something like you want to insert the java.util.Date into an SQL varchar in just that format?

Comment: [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: Why downvoting? I did a lot of research before asking this question.

Comment: Because converting a `String` into a `Date` is no rocket science in Java and is widely covered in tutorials, blog entries and more places in the net.

Comment: "a lot of research"? And you didnt try this? https://www.google.com/search?q=convert%20string%20to%20sql%20date

Comment: Yes, I did try that indeed

Comment: I already tried as I posted above, but when I call the toString of the sqlDate, I get 06-10-2013, or something in that kind

Comment: Now that you have updated the code, it is easier to understand **your real problem**.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I appreciate it. I'll take a look at the other question

Comment: I've updated the question to understand your real problem.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to ask my questions a little clearer from now on

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(javaDate.getTime());
```

[`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) stores the date part of your timestamp. If you want/need to handle both date and time, use [`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) instead:

```
java.sql.Timestamp date = new java.sql.Timestamp (javaDate.getTime());
```

More info:

- [Date vs TimeStamp vs calendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17916666/1065197)

Comment: First correct answer!

Answer (score 1):

You will use a SimpleDateFormat object to parse the string to java.util.date and then use the getTime() method to instantiate a java.sql.Date.

```
    String input = "06/10/2013 18:29:09";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    java.util.Date dt = sdf.parse(input);
    java.sql.Date dtSql = new java.sql.Date(dt.getTime());
```

Comment: Check the code from OP. He's doing this exactly and it is failing.

Comment: Yup - Agree with other comments. He needs to use Timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with String type for date input and then you want to save that in a database like MySQL, you should use an appropriate Date Format for it. There's a class called "**SimpleDateFormat**" which you can use for that purpose. You can find a sample in the following link, also a brief explanation on how it works. Hope it helps.

**Example:** http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/SimpleDateFormat.htm

Best Regards.

Comment: Instead of linking to a tutorial, it would be better to provide an example. Usage of `SimpleDateFormat` is no rocket science.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple demo. In a Database table like this.

You can insert into it like this.

```
 //the SQL statement for creating the database table
 create table user(id, integer primary key, username varchar(100), date_created varchar(100));

 //the java code to insert into the table created above.
 try{
 String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());
 String sql = "insert into user(username, date_created) values('olupotd', '"+date+"')";
 int done = statement.executeUpdate(sql);
 if(done > 0)
    //inserted
 else
   //not inserted.
 }catch(java.sql.SQLException e){}
```

Hope that helps