# JasperSoft Server - Date vs TimeStamp

Tags: java, date, timestamp, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I was reading about [Date vs TimeStamp vs calendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17916666/date-vs-timestamp-vs-calendar) because I´m sending toprint a report this parameters:

> startDate = 2018-01-01T00:00:00+00:00
>
> endDate = 2018-01-01T00:00:00+00:00

And at the begining of my report y print this variables formated as DD-MM-yyyy.

```
           <textField pattern="dd/MM/yyyy">
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="102" height="30" uuid="a0865739-1233-463e-8f93-77f75024e9dc"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{startDay}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="dd/MM/yyyy">
                <reportElement x="204" y="0" width="102" height="30" uuid="ff76b864-ef55-4fcc-82d5-323c6291b7ed"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{endDay}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
```

> Execute in GMT+0

If I declare the parameter as `Java.util.Date` I get `31-12-2017 23:00:00`

But If I declarea the parameter as `java.sql.Timestamp` I get `01-01-2018 00:00:00`

Comment: Almost certainly a time zone issue. Asking naively, can you use `LocalDate` from `java.time` with Jasper Reports? A `LocalDate` is a date without time of day, so I gather it would eliminate your problem.

Comment: @Willas What is your question? Why JRServer was added as tag?

Comment: @AlexK At login-request in JRServer I have  `userTimeZone=Atalantic/Canary`. And I think the time zone has something to do with how that data is shown. Because the server is supposed to be working in GMT+0 and the Date is in GMT+0 too.

Comment: In jasperserver timezone applied to java.sql.Timestamp and java.sql.Time. 
Java.util.Date is timezone independent in jasperserver. Java.util.Date is used only to date filed like yyyy-MM-dd, and when you use is as timestamp you would get issues.