# Measuring time between hops in network (JAVA)

Tags: java, linux, http, networking, raspberry-pi4

I'm trying to gather data of time that a HTTP request take to travel from 1 node to another in a network, here's a simple network topology that I'm working on:
I'm using Raspberry Pi 4 model B

```
     PC ---- RaspPi(1) ---- RaspPi(2) ---- RaspPi(n) ---- ...
```

Each of these nodes have their own application that can work with HTTP, the idea to gather data is:
Suppose I have a HTTP request that has RaspPi(n) as its destination, now once the request traverse through each node, I logged out the **TIMESTAMP** when it reaches the node, from then I can calculate `DeltaT`, which is the time it takes for my request to travel between 2 consecutive nodes.

I have tried to use:

```
Date now = Calendar.getInstance();
TimeStamp ts = new TimeStamp(now.getTime());
```

And

```
System.currentTimeMillis()
```

to get the TIMESTAMP, the problem is, data that I gathered have **negative DeltaT**, which for example: TIMESTAMP at RaspPi(2) is before TIMESTAMP at RaspPi(1). I've done some searching around and found that the 2 methods I used above are *not monotonic* ([Source 1](https://www.javaadvent.com/2019/12/measuring-time-from-java-to-kernel-and-back.html) and [Source 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978598/will-system-currenttimemillis-always-return-a-value-previous-calls)).
So the other method I'm thinking is to use `System.nanoTime()` but this doesn't seem to work on different JVMs, which is all of my network nodes.

I don't know if there is a better approach to gather these data, or some work around that I can do to fix those methods I used.

Please let me know if I haven't make myself clear. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Why don't you use java.time instead? https://stackoverflow.com/a/32975887/2928853

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting the wall-clock time use `System.currentTimeInMillis`.

`System.nanoTime` can be pretty much arbitrary and should be used for measuring durations of an operation on the same node/machine. You will get arbitrary results if you try to use it to measure the time difference between two different computers.

In some cases, [System.curentTimeInMillis may go backward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978598/will-system-currenttimemillis-always-return-a-value-previous-calls) but I guess you're more likely to observe issues caused by system clocks on those machines being not perfectly synchronized - this is in general challenging and also depends on what time intervals you generally expect to measure (microseconds, milliseconds?).

Check out NTP protocol and how to keep clocks synchronized and take the results you get with a grain of salt.
Here's some good info about this topic: https://codeburst.io/why-shouldnt-you-trust-system-clocks-72a82a41df93 - an interesting piece:

> According to google, there is a 6ms drift in a clock which is synchronised every 30s

An interesting paper relevant to the topic: [Clock Synchronization for One-Way Delay Measurement: A Survey](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-23312-8_1)

Comment: You right, NTP is the answer to synchronize the network clock, thanks :D